# Print the coordinates of the highest point of an .obj file?

Tags: python, 3d, height, .obj

I have never worked on 3D objects with Python so I feel a bit lost.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a program that would detect the highest points of a 3D object (.obj format) and give their coordinates.

I had an idea about comparing each point of the 3D object and only returning the coordinates of the highest one.

I would appreciate any help, even by just telling me where to look at.

---

EDIT: I created a program that returns the maximum elevation of the object.

It works, but how could I make it return not only the maximum elevation of the highest point, but also its coordinates alongside the other axis?

As an example, it would return: the highest point is at 5.04 m. Its coordinates are (xxx, xxx, 5.04). Is there a way to print the coordinates of a given point?

EDIT 2: Here is my actual code. It returns the maximum height of a .obj. I would like it to return the 3-axis coordinates of the highest point.

Could it be possible to apply this code not to the entire object, but only to a part of it? (example: detect the highest point on z between a precise interval on the x and y axis?) I don't know how to work on coordinates with python

```
import sys

filename = 'test2.obj'  # sys.argv[1]

x, y, z = [], [], []

with open(filename) as f:
for line in f:
    line = line[:-1].split(' ')
    if line[0] == 'v':
        y.append(float(line[2]))

print('height max = ' + str(max(y)) +  ' m')

input()
```

Comment: can you add your code you have so far?

Comment: Sure, should have done it earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDIT 2: Here is my actual code. It returns the maximum height of a .obj. I would like it to return the 3-axis coordinates of the highest point.

In your code you only append to the list `y`. You'll also need to append to the respective `x` and `y` lists. You could then find the index of the max value in the `y` list, and then index into the `x` and `z` lists with the same index.

Keeping the x, y, and z values in separate lists is a bit cumbersome. Consider keeping them in a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). All you then need is a single list of these namedtuples.

Consider this as your input file:

```
v 10.307 4.083 4.905
v 1.920 11.778 13.118
v 7.883 17.747 0.258
v 5.085 0.353 10.356
v 8.999 9.146 8.047
```

And the code:

```
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y z')
points = []
filename = 'test2.obj'  # sys.argv[1]

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line[:-1].split(' ')
        if line[0] == 'v':
            x, y, z = map(float, line[1:])
            points.append(Point(x, y, z))

highest_point = max(points, key=lambda point: point.z)
print('Highest point on the z-axis:', highest_point)
print(highest_point.x, highest_point.y, highest_point.z)
```

Output:

```
Highest point on the z-axis: Point(x=1.92, y=11.778, z=13.118)
1.92 11.778 13.118
```

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) takes a keyword argument *key* that allows you to, in this case, make the comparisons on the `z` attribute, instead of the `Point` namedtuple.

> Could it be possible to apply this code not to the entire object, but only to a part of it? (example: detect the highest point on z between a precise interval on the x and y axis?)

Sure. Before finding the max point, filter the list so it only contains points within the interval. For example:

```py
filtered_points = []
for point in points:
    if 9 > point.x > 3 and 10 > point.y > 5:
        filtered_points.append(point)

highest_point = max(filtered_points, key=lambda point: point.z)
print('Highest point on the z-axis between some interval on the x and y axis:', highest_point)
```

Output:

```
Highest point on the z-axis between some interval on the x and y axis: Point(x=8.999, y=9.146, z=8.04)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I had to put this program on hiatus because I had to focus on other tasks, but I'll keep the answer for the moment I will get back to it!